# Internet slow connection after connecting to a custom VPN

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, connection-issues, internet, vpn

I have a custom VPN made at home, and after connecting to it on a computer and access a samba to copy a file, it works and copies the file with ~5MB/s.(WIRED)

But when i do the same operation on an android phone it copies with ~50KB/s.(WIRELESS)

my settings are pretty usual: i have a vpn with:
type: PPTP
server address: MY HOME IP
activated PPP encryption (MPPE)

and that's it, no other settings.

am i missing something? any ideas? thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The transfer speed via a wired connection will always be more than the wireless connection. Additionally few other factors that can affect your throughput are:

1. Interferences from other devices in the wireless routers vicinity. You could tweak the channel settings in your router to select a less crowded channel.
2. The ability of your phone's wireless chip to support high throughput. Here is some info on wireless transfer from [Intel](http://blogs.intel.com/technology/2010/02/the_black_and_white_worlds/).